# Laravel validate a quantity field in an array of arrays

Tags: laravel

`selected_products` is an array of arrays

```
^ array:7 [▼
  "selected_products" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "quantity" => 10
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "quantity" => 22
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to validate the quantity of each product if greater than or equal to the quantity in stock I want to get a **Out of stock** error

`Product` and `Stock` is a one to one relationship

Product.php

```
public function stock () {
    return $this->morphOne(Stock::class, 'stockable');
}
```

This is what I tried so far

StoreActivityRequest.php

```
'selected_products.*.quantity' => [function ($input, $item) {
    return $item > Product::find($input->id)->stock->quantity;
}]
```

I'm kind lost here

Comment: this is very bad design - what if you have 100 products in request? It will execute 100 queries. I think, you need to move this logic outside of validator - maybe in ProductService etc.

Comment: @maksim this is a farming project. I want to know what fertilizers (products) have been used in an activity (task). So I have multiple inputs in my Create page and the manager add the products used and there won't be too many. Like 5 at most in each activity

Comment: @Maksim maybe you can help me implement this your way though? I never heard of services in Laravel